# Komodo 11 - run script when saving a file

Tags: apache, perl, console, mod-perl, komodo

In my company we are using Komodo 11 for our project written in Perl on the backend and Javascript on the frontend. And there's a problem because we are using mod_perl module on Apache server and every time when we make change in our Perl files we have to restart Apache server to clear cache and see our changes on the server.

Is there a solution in Komodo to run every time console command (restarting Apache server) when saving a file? Because I don't want to restart Apache manually after every change in Perl file.

Answer (score 0):

**Edited to Userscrips, not Run Commands**

You're looking for *Userscripts* in the Toolbox:
http://docs.activestate.com/komodo/11/manual/macros.html

Then use the *shell* module from the Komodo Javascript SDK:
http://docs.activestate.com/komodo/11/sdk/api/module-ko_shell.html

Example:

```
require("ko/shell").exec("ls -la", {}, ()=>{console.log("I ran")})
```

That will run `ls -la`.  You can try that in the Komodo Console, *View Menu > Tabs & Sidebars > Console*.

If you need more information have a look at the docs or post in the Komodo forums.  We answer questions almost daily:
community.komodoide.com

Comment: Thanks. Unfortunately I didn't found anything in Komodo documentation about running commands when making some action, i.e. saving a file.

Comment: Oh that was silly.  I was thinking [Userscripts](http://docs.activestate.com/komodo/11/manual/macros.html#specifying-userscript-triggers).  You can either implement it in JS and use the Komodo SDK which will easily allow you to run a terminal command using [ko/shell](http://docs.activestate.com/komodo/11/sdk/api/module-ko_shell.html) or use Python's `os.system` to execute the command.  Userscripts support both languages.  You would then set the **Trigger** property for the **Userscript** to _After file save_.

I hope that's makes sense.  Sorry for the confusing original Answer.

Comment: Thank you very much. I was trying to write a user script using Komodo SDK, but unfortunately I think it is really bad described how to run this commands and I'm confused now. There are no examples in whole Internet. Did you use this Komodo SDK? Can you write a simple script which performs some operations in cmd (Windows)?

Comment: I help write Komodo so yes I've used the SDK :). I don't have a computer with me for about two weeks so I can't write something for you.  There are examples of using the SDK in the docs.  If you need more help ask in the Komodo forums. Someone will answer within a day I'm sure.

Comment: As i said above, there are examples in the docs if you look. 
 This is the module you'll want to use here. 
http://docs.activestate.com/komodo/11/sdk/api/module-ko_shell.html

So it'll be something like `require("ko/shell").exec("ls -la", {}, ()=>{console.log("I ran")})`.

You put that in a macro, set the trigger property to run on save and you're done.